# How can i get data from controller to jsp when ajax call happens in jsp?

Tags: ajax, spring

I am trying to get the data from controller when ajax call happens in jsp.But it is not returning any value. How to display the value in jsp page.

lineChart.jsp

```
$(function(){ 
     $.ajax({url: "lineBar", async: false, 
         success: function(result) { 
           /* ${cse} */
           /* ${ec} */
           /* ${it} */
});
```

EmployeeController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/lineBar")
@ResponseBody
public String lineBarChart(Model model) throws Exception
{
  int cseCount = 4, ecCount = 5, itCount = 6;
  System.out.println(cseCount);
  model.addAttribute("cse", cseCount);
  model.addAttribute("ec", ecCount);
  model.addAttribute("it", itCount);

  return "lineBarChart";}
```

Here i am including the lineChart.jsp page.

```
<div class="col-md-6 p-1">
<jsp:include page="lineChart.jsp"/>
</div>
```

Comment: you should return the model and not string to the front end

Comment: once you see the value in the console.log(result) you can use inner html to display the value https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_innerhtml_ul